# Markov property question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, finance

In every book I can find, the Markov property for ito diffusions, $E[f(X_{t+h})\mid F_s] = E^{X_t}f(X_h)$ is stated for $\textbf{bounded}$ Borel functions.

However, I have the following statement from a set of notes:
$$g(t,S_t) = E[(S_T-K)^{+}\mid F_t]$$

Where $g$ is some Borel function.

How can this be justified? Our $f$ here is $(x-K)^+$ which is not bounded.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the Markov property for Itô diffusions rather reads $E[f(X_{t+h})\mid F_t] = E[f(X_{t+h})\mid X_t]$. (In a second phase, the *stationarity* of the transitions of these processes then yields $E[f(X_{t+h})\mid X_t] = E^{X_t}[f(X_h)]$, that is, more explicitely, $E[f(X_{t+h})\mid X_t] = g(X_t)$ where, for every $x$, $g(x)=E^x[f(X_h)]$.) This holds for every Borel function $f$ such that $f(X_s)$ is integrable for every $s$.

Comment: I don't see how you are getting this to hold for every Borel $f$ such that $f(X_s)$ is integrable since in order to prove your first equality I must have boundedness of $f.$

Comment: No. One often takes as definition the property when $f$ is Borel and bounded, but then the property holds more generally for every Borel measurable $f$ such that the expectations of $f(X_t)$ are finite for every $t$.

Comment: Ok. I guess the proof I have which uses bounded convergence theorem of conditional expectations can be extended to this result by truncating $f$ and using dominated convg for each $t$. Thanks!

Comment: May you explain more about how to use stationarity to show the second identity? For your information, I asked the same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754077/markov-property-of-ito-diffusion).

Comment: @JohnZHANG By stationarity the conditional distributions $\mu_t$ of $X_{t+h}$ conditionally on $X_t=x$ and $\mu_0$ of $X_{h}$ conditionally on $X_0=x$ coincide. Now, $$E(f(X_{t+h}\mid X_t)=g_t(X_t)\qquad g_t(x)=\int f(y)\mu_t(dy\mid x),$$ and $$E^x(f(X_{h})=E(f(X_h)\mid X_0=x)=g_0(x)\qquad g_0(x)=\int f(y)\mu_0(dy\mid x),$$ hence $\mu_t=\mu_0$ implies these conditional expectations coincide. In terms of transition probabilities, if they exist, $$E(f(X_{t+h})\mid X_t)=\int f(x)p_{t,t+h}(X_t,x)dx$$ hence the result holds if $$p_{t,t+h}=p_{0,h},$$ which is stationarity.

Comment: @Did May I confirm that in your above comments, you have provided two arguments about the same result, one use conditionally distributions and the other one use transition probability? And the argument using transition probability may not work because they may not exist but the proof using conditional distribution always works.

Comment: @JohnZHANG Yes.