# Markov property of ito diffusion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Most books show Ito diffusions satisfy Markov property, that is, $E[f(X_{t+h})\mid F_t]=E^{X_t}[f(X_h)]$.
But I was wondering whether it's true that  $E[f(X_{t+h})\mid X_t]=E^{X_t}[f(X_h)]$.

In this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931818/markov-property-question), it seems that stationarity of transition of the processes implies 
$E[f(X_{t+h})\mid X_t] = E^{X_t}[f(X_h)]$. If it's true, my question is solved. But I don't know why $E^{X_t}[f(X_h)]$ is $X_t$ measurable and how to connect it to the transition probability.